# running a linux command against a pid inside k8 pod

Tags: kubernetes, jmap

Is it possible to run a linux command against a process which is running inside a kubernetes pod. Example: I want to grab heapdumps on a java process running inside a k8 pod. The pod comes with minimal installation and does not have that much disk space either, so I want to run jmap command from local machine (pointing to k8 cluster). Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use [kubectl exec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have already mentioned in the comments, what you can use is the [kubectl exec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec) command:

> Execute a command in a container.
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> $ kubectl exec (POD | TYPE/NAME) [-c CONTAINER] [flags] -- COMMAND [args...]
> ```

The `kubectl exec` command is a tool that allows you to inspect and debug your applications, by executing commands inside your containers.

If you need more details and examples regarding how to use it, I recommend these two guides:

- [Get a Shell to a Running Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/): This page shows how to use `kubectl exec` to get a shell to a running container.
- [How does `kubectl exec` work?](https://erkanerol.github.io/post/how-kubectl-exec-works/)

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl exec` did it. It allows to run any command inside the container. For example:

```
kc exec <POD_NAME> -- jmap -dump:live,format=b,file=heapdump.bin <pid>
```